# Azure Data Factory copy data from XML to SQL Synapse pool

Tags: sql, xml, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I've created a SQL Dedicated pool table in Synapse, and now trying to copy data from multiple XML files to this database

I've mapped all fields from the XML file that I need to each specific column in the destination table, but the following error is blocking the copy data activity:

> Message=Column count in target table does not match column count specified in input. If BCP command, ensure format file column count matches destination table. If SSIS data import, check column mappings are consistent with target.,Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=107098,Class=16,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=1,Errors=[{Class=16,Number=107098,State=1,Message=Column count in target table does not match column count specified in input. If BCP command, ensure format file column count matches destination table. If SSIS data import, check column mappings are consistent with target.,},],'

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the count of column in the XML files and Synapse is not equal. You need to check the count of your XML files and make them be same as the count of your sink's column.

Comment: If you're only interested in two out of three columns, what then?